# DynamicDataDisplay zoom and tooltips on realtime charts with syncronous X axis

Tags: c#, charts, dynamic-data-display

Some time ago I posted the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787080/how-to-make-the-x-axis-shared-for-2-charts-in-wpf-in-d3) about synchronous charts. I found the solution here, but I still have some problems.

- I need to zoom in and out on Y axis on StrokeChart to see my date. I don't know why, but the range doesn't change on next added point. Actually range is 0-1 on Y axis. It's strange, but I can live with that
- The second question is: how to configure zoom on chart area? I want it to zoom only Y axis when I scroll up/down.
- And last, but not least: How to make realtime tooltips on chart which is build using ObservableCollection? It can be done for EnumerableDataSource easy. you can check [this](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/50842) and [this](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/270138). I tried to do thing described by user "Thecentury", but it doesn't work. I even added method `AddMapping` to ObservableCollection and rebuilt the library, but it still doesn't work. So I don't know what to do next.

I appreciate for any help and advice.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **zooming** I think I managed to solve the problem.

In **MouseNavigation.cs** add new properties

```
// 2014-02-22 - MPEKALSKI - added property to make possible
                         limiting on zoom on only one axis
private bool? _zoomX;
/// <summary>
/// Property for allowing/disallowing for zoom along X axis. By default allowed (true).
/// </summary>
public bool zoomX
{
    get { return _zoomX ?? true; }
    set { _zoomX = value; }
}
private bool? _zoomY;
/// <summary>
/// Property for allowing/disallowing for zoom along Y axis. By default allowed (true).
/// </summary>
public bool zoomY
{
    get { return _zoomY ?? true; }
    set { _zoomY = value; }
}
```

In the same class modify the method

```
private void MouseWheelZoom(Point mousePos, int wheelRotationDelta)
```

by substituting

```
Viewport.Visible = Viewport.Visible.Zoom(zoomTo, zoomSpeed);
```

with

```
    // 2014-02-23 - MPEKALSKI - if we do not allow for change in Y
    //                          then keep the old value, by analogy for X
    Rect zoomedRect = Viewport.Visible.Zoom(zoomTo, zoomSpeed);
    if (zoomY == false) { zoomedRect.Y = Viewport.Visible.Y; 
                          zoomedRect.Height = Viewport.Visible.Height; }
    if (zoomX == false) { zoomedRect.X = Viewport.Visible.X;
                          zoomedRect.Width = Viewport.Visible.Width; }
    Viewport.Visible = zoomedRect;
```

The use now is pretty straightforward given chartPlotter object just set properties zoomY or zoomX to false to prevent zooming along this axis.

```
chartPlotter2.MouseNavigation.zoomY = false;
```

I do not know is it the most optimal solution, but it works for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314071/dynamicdatadisplay-d3chartplotter-zoom-proplem - there is a build in solution, but it requires scrolling over the axis.